# Call Encryption

Tags: security, calls, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt calls on Android OS?

How do I do that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Curently there is no such official support and the SDK does not allow third party apps to encrypt calls, but if you use a SIP client, the call can be encrypted depending on the SIP client`s features.

Answer (score 8):

Yes with an app called redphone: http://www.appbrain.com/app/redphone-beta/org.thoughtcrime.redphone

Answer (score 3):

Options are limited unfortunately.

- If you want to make calls using your existing phone service with your existing number, then your best option is [Red Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.redphone) from Whisper Systems. Of course, your calling partner will need to have the app to for the call to be encrypted.
- If you don't mind using another service, take a look at [OStel](http://ostel.me), a secure VOIP provider.